# Get values from below string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am a beginner to regex.

I have below String:

**fail:2,success:1,fetch:1**

Output Map: **Get Map which contains all key-values as below:**

fail - 2 (key=fail, value=2)

success - 1

fetch - 1

I have tried using below solution:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {            
String msg = "fail:1,success:1,policyfetch:1"; 
System.out.println(getKeyValuesFromMsg(msg));  
}                                                  

public static Map getKeyValuesFromMsg(String msg) {
  if (msg != null) {                             
    Map keyvalues = new HashMap();             
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):(,+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);                
    while (m.find()) {                         
        keyvalues.put(m.group(1), m.group(2)); 
    }                                          
    return keyvalues;                          
} else                                         
    return Collections.emptyMap();             
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with that solution?

Comment: not get any output

Comment: PS `Map keyvalues = new HashMap();` - usage of raw types is rather bad practice (more reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Comment: Your regex is wrong, `m.find()` returns false and your loop is never executed.

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya Check my answer below. If the data is as simple as you have shown in your example. You can simply use the split function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the split function, The following snippet should work fine

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
    String str = "fail:2,success:1,fetch:1";
    String[] keyValueParts = str.split(",");
    for(String s  : keyValueParts){
        String parts[] = s.split(":");
        map.put(parts[0],parts[1]);
    }

    System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

i would have used below method for the same.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {            
    String msg = "fail:1,success:1,policyfetch:1"; 
    System.out.println(getKeyValuesFromMsg(msg));  
    }

private static Map<Object, Object> getKeyValuesFromMsg(String msg) {
    Map<Object,Object> mapObj = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
    for (int i=0;i<msg.split(",").length;i++)
    mapObj.put(msg.split(",")[i].split(":")[0],msg.split(",")[i].split(":")[1]);
    return mapObj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

my solution:

```
    public static Map<String, Integer> trans2Map(String source) {
    if (null == source) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(source.split(","))
            .filter(pair -> pair.split(":").length == 2)
            .forEach(pair -> {
                String key = pair.split(":")[0];
                Integer value;
                try {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(pair.split(":")[1]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
                result.put(key, value);
            });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1. Why parsing to `int`? OP didn't ask about it. Furthemore, if value is not a number, the map will contain `null` for that key. 2. check for `null != pair` is redundant - `String#split` will never return array with nulls. 3. `source.isEmpty()` check is redundant - your check for "contains colon" in the stream's filter will handle it. 4. Why the `trim()`? OP didn't ask about it either - what if the spaces matter?

Comment: @ Jaroslaw Pawlak thanks for your comment： (1)、why parsing to int? this method just a demo，the map will contain null for that key(if value is not a number), really? (2)、you are right （3）、you are right （4）、 fix

Comment: 1. no, sorry, my bad - I missed the `return;` in the catch :) By the way, when using stream API you should try to make as many small operations as possible, rather than having big blocks of code. That one in `forEach` can be converted into `map`, `filter`, `map` and `collect`. Also, modification of variables outside the stream is not a good practice (this `result.put`) and you should use collectors instead.